# How to make Android Studio show error message for the source layout file?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

One simple error as following may be the best way to explain my question:

```
 E:\...\AndroidstudioProjects\androidLibrary\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\release\layout\fragment_foo.xml
Error:(63, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/model').
```

Clicking the error message opens the intermediate file. Editing the intermediate file has no use for correcting the error.  This is the case for all layout files using data binding.

How can Android Studio be made to show errors of the original, not intermediate, layout file?

Comment: I have a bad habit of editing the intermediate file and rebuilding before realizing what I did upon the error occurring again, so I'm wondering the same thing.